# Recurrence relation for the number of bit strings that contain the string $01$

Tags: recurrence-relations

Find the recurrence relation for the number of bit strings that contain the string **$01$**

I know it is answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881005/find-the-recurrence-relation-for-the-number-of-bit-strings-that-contain-the-stri)

But i have a doubt.I mean i just want to check my approach,where it is wrong!!

For Finding recurence relation containing $01$,$a_{n}$ 
Lets us start with String starting with $1$,

**case 1**: If it starts with $1$ $\Rightarrow$ ,it may contain $01$ in $a_{n-1}$

Starting with $11$ is covered in case 1

**case 2**:Starting With $01$ check in other $2^{n-2}$ sets

Thus can't we write $a_{n}=a_{n-1}+2^{n-2}$ ???
Where i am wrong please correct me !!

Comment: Isn't that just all $2^n$ bit strings minus the $n+1$ strings $1\ldots 10\ldots 0$?

Comment: I don't understand case $1$.  The string $101$ starts with $1$ yet it contains $01$.

Comment: @lulu i meant that only .that if it start with $1$ then go and check $01$ in   $a_{n-1}$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen i am not getting you !

Comment: Still not following.  You say "if it starts with $1\implies$ No chance it will contain $01$."  Maybe you meant something entirely different, but how are we to guess?

Comment: @lulu i had made mistake in expressing ..i meant that if it starts with $1$ then we have to check $01$ in  $a_{n-1}$ ! i will update my question!

Comment: I don't know what "check in" means.  This is all very vague.  Let's do small $n$.  $a_1=0$, yes?  There are no strings of length $1$ that contain $01$.  So then you tell me that $a_2=0+1=1$ which is true!  Good.  Now $a_3$.  You tell me $a_3=a_2+2=1+2=3$.  But we have $011,010,001,101$.  So, we have a problem.  Go through your argument carefully and see where it breaks down for $n=3$.

Comment: But, honestly, the problem is trivial. Look at strings that do not contain $01$.  That means that, whenever a $0$ occurs all subsequent characters must also be $0$.  Thus we only have $1^a0^b$.  Easy to count those.

Comment: @lulu,i think $a_{n-1}+2^{n-2}$ is creating problem because whenever we are seeing a $1$,we are switching to $a_{n-1}$,while it may contain $0$ before it which will count to $01$thus it is not counting as per expectation

Comment: Well.  One obvious problem with your method is that you appear to be assuming that every good string either begins with $1$ or $01$, which is obviously false.  For $a_3$ this causes you to omit $001$.  But, really, go over the easy way to do it (outlined in my prior comment).

Comment: @lulu you are right ! i did not use $0$ as a "starting good string" because there will no be scope of counting it if the next string is $1$ and hence my equation fails ..thankx for pointing it out!